# Building up functions from data

Tags: argument-patterns

Have a tricky Mathematica problem. I am trying to build up functions from data to automate my processes with a minimum of hardcoding.

So let's say I have some data:

```
myList = {"e1", "e2", "e3", "e4"};
```

I want these strings to become symbols that are arguments to a function.

Here's how I do that:

```
args = Map[ToExpression[# <> "_"] &, myList] /. List -> Sequence
```

which returns:

```
Sequence[e1_, e2_, e3_, e4_]
```

All good. Now I make myself a list of symbols that I can use inside my function, say with Map:

```
variables = Map[ToExpression[#] &, myList]
```

which returns:

```
{e1, e2, e3, e4}
```

Now when I reference the symbol directly in a function:

```
Clear[f];
f[args] := Block[{},
e1
]
```

`f[10, 20, 30, 0]` returns `10`, which is perfect. But, I don't want to refer to my symbols directly. Rather I want to refer to them indirectly:

```
Clear[f];
f[args] := Block[{},
variables[[1]]
]
```

`f[10, 20, 30, 0]` returns `e1`, which is not what I want. I want it to return `10` as above. I've tried a number of variations of the function, but none work. Can someone help?

Thanks in advance,

George Danner

Comment: Well well Mr. Danner. Good to see you here.

Comment: Is it necessary to use SetDelayed ,:=? If you use Set ,=, your function works without any problems.

Answer (score 5):

Using [Pattern](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pattern.html) 
  and [PatternSequence](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PatternSequence.html);

```
ClearAll[f, args];
myList = {"e1", "e2", "e3", "e4"};
args = Map[ToExpression[# <> "_"] &, myList] /. List -> PatternSequence
(* or PatternSequence @@ (Pattern[#, _] & /@ (ToExpression /@ myList)); *)
(* or PatternSequence @@ (Pattern[#, _] & /@ (Symbol /@ myList)); *)

f[a : args] := Block[{}, {a}[[1]]]
f[10, 0, 2, 3]
(* 10 *)
```

Comment: Thank you @kguler!  That works beautifully!

Comment: @GeorgeD, my pleasure. You might consider Accepting/Upvoting an answer if you find it useful.

Comment: `args = Map[ ToExpression[# <> "_"] &, myList]; f[Sequence@@args] := Evaluate[ First@args[[1]] ]` seems to do the job also.